# How to get window login account name with angular 9?

Tags: angular, web, angular9

I'm working on the angular project and might need to get the user account name from pc. Is there any way to make it? I test around `this.deviceInfo = deviceService.getDeviceInfo();` only able to get the system info.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, the modern browsers don't allow you to do that out of the box.
There are a bunch of articles on that. And here is an interesting one on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/can-your-windows-or-linux-username-be-exposed-to-websites).

You might get some results if you use some plugin on the browser side (Flash, ActiveX, whatever).
Another old solution was letting the user select a file for upload and then find the user name from the file path, but that was closed recently in the browsers.

But in general if you'd like to somehow identify your users, or get another bunch of data about their browser/environment, you might consider checking the [FingerprintJS](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs2) that can do that with 99.5% accuracy.